# Empty Production Items screen

Tags: xcom-ufo-defense

I'm playing a DOSBox (0.74) version of XCOM UFO Defence and I don't have any options for Production Items on the New Production screen.

I'm wondering whether I'm seeing a DOSBox emulation problem or that it's just too early in the game to get that option...

I have engineers, Workshop and the funds.

Bug or impatience?

Comment: Stand down, false alert. Just found [link](http://www.ufopaedia.org/index.php?title=Manufacturing)

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned in the comment immediately below my question, I soon found [a site that goes into detail about all aspects of XCOM](http://www.ufopaedia.org/index.php?title=Manufacturing).

So, the answer to my question is: To see any options in the Production Items screen you need to have researched an appropriate technology beforehand.

Game on.